# How to Configure TimeOut For AJP connector

Tags: apache-2.2, load-balancing, jboss, ajp

I am using ajp connector to connect to J BOSS nodes from Apache, ajp is configured to accept 400 concurrent connections by setting max Threads to 400, but few my connections are getting timeout. Where to configure timeout period for ajp connector, in Jboss? or in Apache's workers.properties file?

**AJP Configuration is as follows:**

```
Max threads: 400
Current thread count: 78
Current thread busy: 15
Max processing time: 301287 ms
Processing time: 108458.98 s
Request count: 509878
Error count: 12
Bytes received: 281.95 MB
Bytes sent: 1216.30 MB
```

**worker.properties**:

```
worker.node1.port=8009
worker.node1.host=cedlab030as1
worker.node1.type=ajp13
worker.node1.lbfactor=1
worker.node1.prepost_timeout=200000
worker.node1.ping_mode=A
```

Comment: Please post both the AJP connector config from JBoss and proxy config from Apache.

Comment: AJP Configuration is as follows:                                 Max threads: 400 
Current thread count: 78 
Current thread busy: 15 
Max processing time: 301287 ms 
Processing time: 108458.98 s 
Request count: 509878 
Error count: 12 
Bytes received: 281.95 MB 
Bytes sent: 1216.30 MB                                            worker.propertes are as follows: worker.node1.port=8009
worker.node1.host=cedlab030as1
worker.node1.type=ajp13
worker.node1.lbfactor=1
worker.node1.prepost_timeout=200000
worker.node1.ping_mode=A #As of mod_jk 1.2.27

Comment: What you posted about AJP is the status, not the config, which is in `server.xml` under the jbossweb component (not knowing the actual version of JBoss you're using can't tell the exact path) which should be similar to this: `<Connector port="8009" address="${jboss.bind.address}" protocol="AJP/1.3" emptySessionPath="true" enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443" URIEncoding="UTF-8" maxThreads="500" connectionTimeout="60000" />`

Comment: Please always edit the your question when adding relevant information to the topic so that others don't need to read through the comments.

Comment: In addition to the above, could you also explain in further detail the usage of the application being server on JBoss and how did you find out about the timeouts, maybe from some logs (if so, please post relevant parts)? Are the timeouts reported in the client or in Apache? Is there anything in common in the situations when timeouts occur (during peak hours, during certain kind of requests)?